# How to add header in Multiplication table using while loop c++

Tags: c++, multiplication

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 

    int startAt = 1;
    int i = startAt;

    while (i <= 10){ 
        int j = startAt;

        while (j <= 10) {
            cout<<"\t"<<i*j;
            j+=1;
        }

        cout<<endl;
        i+=1; 
    }
}
```

This is my code and I want my output to have header 1-10. Hope you'll help. Thank you!

Comment: Add a new loop before the nested loop.

Comment: for-loop seems more natural than while-loop here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw), or even better [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) from the standard library to set the column width.
`\t` is not the right tool for this.

Also, to be very practical, you can just dump the output with a single character (any) as a column separator and pipe it through `column -t`, if you are in a Unix-like environment. This will auto-detect and auto-align columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear really what you want. If you want 1-10 above every table so may be you are trying to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int startAt = 1;
    int i = startAt;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cout << "\t" << "1-10";
    cout << endl;

    while (i <= 10) {
        int j = startAt;
    
        while (j <= 10) {
            cout << "\t" << i * j;
            j += 1;
        }

        cout << endl;
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this was required really. Also, it breaks the formatting. I think the OP wanted number 1 to 10 printed at the beginning of each column/row.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int startAt = 1;
    int i = startAt;

    for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
        cout << "\t" << i;
    cout << "\n    --------------------------------------\n";


    while (i <= 10) {
        int j = startAt;
        cout << setw(2) << i <<"|";
    
        while (j <= 10) {
            cout << "\t" << i * j;
            j += 1;
        }

        cout << endl;
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

The output would be:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
    --------------------------------------
 1| 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
 2| 2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
 3| 3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
 4| 4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
 5| 5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
 6| 6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
 7| 7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
 8| 8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
 9| 9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10| 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```